# Implicit type class defined for Map not found for a SortedMap

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

In a following code (extracted from my attempt to extend [Quicklens](https://github.com/adamw/quicklens) support to a `SortedMap`) the pimped `upd` is available for a `Map`, but not for a `SortedMap`.

Why - and how can I change the code so that `UpdatedMap` takes care of `SortedMap` (and other possible `Map` subclasses)?

```
object TImpl extends App {

  trait UpdatedTrait[A, K, T] {
    def upd(k: K, t: T): A
  }

  trait UpdatedFunctor[A, K, T] {
    def upd(a: A, k: K, t: T): A
  }

  implicit class UpdatedMap[M[KT, TT] <: Map[KT, TT], K, T](a: M[K, T])(implicit f: UpdatedFunctor[M[K, T], K, T]) {
    def upd(k: K, t: T) = {
      f.upd(a, k, t)
    }
  }

  implicit def mapUpdatedFunctor[M[KT, TT] <: Map[KT, TT], K, T] = new UpdatedFunctor[M[K, T], K, T] {
    override def upd(a: M[K, T], k: K, t: T): M[K, T] = {
      a.updated(k, t).asInstanceOf[M[K, T]]
    }
  }

  val m = Map("A" -> "1")
  val sm = collection.SortedMap("A" -> "1")

  val mt = m.upd("A", "2")
  val smt: collection.SortedMap[String, String] = sm.upd("A", "2")

  println(mt)
  println(smt)
}
```

Comment: If anyhow sees a way how to get rid of that `asInstanceOf`, I have asked a related question about that on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119005/avoid-asinstanceof-in-a-type-class-implementation), feel free to answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because `SortedMap` extends `scala.collection.Map`.

Where as you have set a bound for `M[KT, TT] <: scala.collection.immutable.Map[KT, TT]`. Change both the bound's to `scala.collection.Map` and it works. Or probably you intended it to use `scala.collection.immutable. SortedMap`

If you wish it to run for all types of Map (i.e. mutable, immutable and collection), I am not sure if it is practical. Or probably with implicit conversions with a wrapper, but that would be ugly.